# Error: 'Object of type "TYPO3\Media\Domain\Model\Image" with identity "image.jpg" not found.'

Tags: php, fluid, typo3-flow

What does this error exactly mean?
'Object of type "TYPO3\Media\Domain\Model\Image" with identity "image.jpg" not found.'

I have a form like this:

```
        <f:form id="nativeFormSuggest" action="create" objectName="user">
            <f:form.upload property="image" />
            <f:form.submit value="submit" />
        </f:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's PersistentObjectConverter exception. `TYPO3\Media\Domain\Model\Image` is `Entity` which has persitence identifier (sth like `48c1765e-6633-4304-b454-19ae9e0e058a`). Fluid forms automaticaly translates entity objects to their identifiers, and they are converted back to object before action in your controller is called.

Somehow instead of image identifier you submit 'image.jpg' string - it cannot be converted, it's not valid persitence identifier and you have this exception. Please check [resource upload example](http://flowframework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartIII/ResourceManagement.html#resource-uploads). If it won't help paste your action (CreateAction) and entity (User?) code.